# IOS Swift App - How to mute a incoming call notification?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to silence an incoming call notification?

One example would be:
In native camera app -> start video recording -> have an incoming call. Notice the call does not have sound nor vibration.
OR
During an incoming call, press the volume button and it will stop ringing/vibrating.

Using below code, I was able to disable sound and vibration for notifications.

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording(false)
```

However, call and alarms still goes through.

Reading an old [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW23), is there no way for us to silence it?

> The system deactivates your audio session for a Clock or Calendar alarm or an incoming phone call. When the user dismisses the alarm, or chooses to ignore a phone call, the system allows your session to become active again.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, I don't think you can mute incoming calls but you can identify and block incoming calls using callKit

```
class CustomCallDirectoryProvider: CXCallDirectoryProvider {
override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
    let blockedPhoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ … ]
    for phoneNumber in blockedPhoneNumbers.sorted(by: <) {
        context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
    }
    
    context.completeRequest()
}
```

}

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit#2624967

Comment: Hmm, yes I do know there's CallKit, but I don't think it's a good idea to block incoming call for an app